# i am developing ball game. i am stuck at i want 3 balls are moving top bottom but every time with random width

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, animation

I have a ball-game. width of board is 600px. 3 ball at that time coming down and on click it disappearing. but i want to have a one time 3 balls should be coming from different places. top 0 but left amount should be different. i write css

```
@keyframes ball-move {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

For generate random width i make var.

```
var boardWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600 + 1);
```

but i am not understanding how can i over right css in JS. i want to have top:0 to enter ball in frame but i want to enter from different width.

i tried with entering in css over ride but.JS is not reading my css.
I have to use only HTML, CSS,j javascript only.

Comment: can i see your html at the balls part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each ball a class of ball and select them with javascript to loop through and set custom CSS

```
document.querySelectAll('.ball').forEach(ball => {
   ball.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ball to fall down from differenct place every time, you may use "on animationiteration". The below will set a new left value to the ball everytime the animation is itreataed.

The line

```
// Get all ball class element and loop through each
$(".ball").each(function(){
    // Set random initial left value for tha ball
    let boardWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
    $(this).css("left", boardWidth + "px");
          
    // Set random left everytime the animation is iterated
    $(this).on("animationiteration", function() {
        let boardWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
        $(this).css("left", boardWidth + "px");
    })
}
```

For the function you are using for boardWidth, you may want to consider taking the ball width into account as well, currently your ball may not be shown on the UI when left: 600px.